# Unable to use cuDNN cudnn64_7.dll file with Alea GPU (it keeps looking for the older dll)

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I'm having a hard time getting Alea use the newer cuDNN `cudnn64_7.dll` library.

I've already followed the official guide [here](http://www.aleagpu.com/release/3_0_4/doc/faq.html#config_cuda_version) and added the environment variable to let Alea reference the newer CUDA 9.1 drivers.

The problem though is with **cuDNN** specifically, which is just a standalone .dll that's added in the CUDA bin folder (along with its header and lib file).

Right now Alea throws an exception as soon as I try to use one of the methods in the `CuDnn` class.
Is there a way to explicitly set Alea to reference the newer dll instead of the older one it tries to find?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the following to your `App.config` file?

```
<aleaSettings>
    <cuBLAS version="9.1"/>
    <cuRAND version="9.1"/>
    <cuDNN version="7"/>
</aleaSettings>
```

In particular, note the `cuDNN` part, which isn't mentioned in the official guide you linked to.

Comment: Hello, I've tried adding that config file to both the library and/or the test application, Alea.Gpu still fails and throws the same `DllNotFoundException` saying it can't find the `cudnn64_7.dll` file (I had removed it to test if it was working).
At this point I'm wondering whether we just need to wait for a future Alea.Gpu update that uses the newer .dll file.